# Compute covariance matrix of $KAA^Tv$ where A is a random matrix.

Tags: probability, statistics

I need to compute covariance matrix of an expression like $KAA^Tv$, where $A$ is a matrix with random elements, $v$ is a random vector and $K$ is a constant matrix. Suppose that $E[A]=0$ and its elements are uncorrelated with $v$. I chose the distribution of $A$ if that helps. Is there any guidelines on how to deal with such problems like some well known identities?

Comment: How do you define the _co_-variance of a single entity? You mean the variance?

Comment: Sorry, I meant covariance matrix. $KAA^Tv$ is a vector.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot go very far, because expected values of self-products will be involved. The assumption $E(A) = 0$ does not help anywhere, while the uncorrelatedness assumption must be strengthened to independence to at least be able to separate to some degree expected values. Given independence of $A$ and $v$,

$$ E\Big[(KAA^Tv)(KAA^Tv)^T\Big] - E\Big[(KAA^Tv)\Big]\Big[E(KAA^Tv)\Big]^T $$

$$ = KE\Big(AA^Tvv^TAA^T\Big)K^T - KE(AA^T)E(v)E(v^T)E(AA^T)K^T $$

$$ = K\Big (E\Big(AA^Tvv^TAA^T\Big) - E(AA^T)E(v)E(v^T)E(AA^T)\Big )K^T $$

You cannot break further the first expected value component, because while $A$ and $v$ are assumed independent (and so any function of them is also independent), $AA^T$ is not independent of itself.